# UnZoom UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, rotation, objective-c-blocks

I have a UIScrollView , and enabled scrolling . Its working fine with delegate methods.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return MyScrollView;
}
```

But the problem i am facing is, i need to Zoom out the UIScrollView when I rotate the iPad.
What I have to code in this function

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
       interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

    }
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
       interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method: `- (void)setZoomScale:(float)scale animated:(BOOL)animated` and set the scale to minimum zoom scale of your scrollview that you might have configured when you have created the scrollview.

Example:

[MyScrollview setZoomScale:minimuzoomscale animated:YES];

Place above line in shouldAutorotate.

Comment: my view is zooming now. but i need to cancel zoom when i rotate .any idea

Comment: Suppose before rotate your scrollview's zoomscale is 3.0 so after rotate it should be reset to minimum or 1.0 right?

Answer (score 2):

just put

```
[YourScrollView setMaximumZoomScale:1];
[YourScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:1];
```

in your orientation.